# Git merge --no-commit tracked files without committing them

Tags: git, merge

On branch A I had two 'stories', one which I wanted committed to master, one I did not.

As these changes were not on feature branches, I needed to separate the two somehow. I used

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff A
```

while on master. This gave me a staging area to tweak as expected, and I

```
git reset file
```

on those files relating to the unwanted commit. Is this approach incorrect? The result was unexpected. The files were not added (as desired) but the record of them was. Git tracked them as removed files! Now when merging back into A from master it tries to delete the uncommitted work. Its very strange as master never had some of these files. This is extremely inconvenient, can anyone suggest how I might go about 'synchronising' these changes? Or perhaps a better approach going forward, why would --no-commit do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most clean way is to create two branches `story1` and `story2` from the mergebase of A and master. Then separate `A` commits by cherry-picking and editing/spitting commits. So you have two new branches for each story separately. Then you could easily merge.

Comment: A good approach, but I was hoping to avoid the overhead of cherry-picking, which is why I used --no-commit to do it by file. Is this a bug or should --no-commit work this way? I have commit log entries for files that were not even added to the branch. Why would it do this?

Comment: @marked You are merging two histories. And it means all commits are appear in the merged history. So, it means merged branch would have a history entry for the file added, and then, during the merge, it was deleted. Sounds very straigt forward, it describes exactly that you have done, isn't it? While cherry-picking means you are selectively choosing what do you want to pick from a history.

Comment: The substantial difference between the selective merge you are doing and splitting branches is that if you do the merge choosing only story1 changes, you will unable to merge story2 changes later, as you could not *remerge*. But the splitted branches could be merged in any order.

Comment: Why could I not remerge? If I am understanding you correctly, then git merge --no-commit would be seem to be far less useful than I thought. It records a history of non-existent files, detrimentally effecting future merges, surely this is dangerous? What then is the purpose of --no-commit? Thanks for your responses thus far!

Comment: @marked It doesn't record anything, it creates a *merge commit* which merges histories of both branches. Once the diverged histories merged, another merge attempt will do nothing, because all commits are united in the merged history already. `no-commit` is useful if you want do small amendmends after a merge.